# RIP Gahan Wilson

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

I just learned of the passing last Thursday of cartoonist and author [Gahan Wilson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gahan_Wilson). Although most of us know of him from his macabre cartoons (the New Yorker  posted [a retrospective](https://www.newyorker.com/culture/postscript/the-beautifully-macabre-cartoons-of-gahan-wilson) of them in his memory), he was also a published SF author.

Wilson's best-known story, from Harlan Ellison's anthology *Again, Dangerous Visions*, doesn't even have a "title": It's just a little ink blob on the page that's also one of the main characters.

Comment: I've seen that listed as "*", "blot", "spot" and "[spot]".

Comment: @DavidW Also ["Inksplot"](https://books.google.com/books?id=qMikAwAAQBAJ&pg=PP5&lpg=PP5&dq=inksplot)

Answer (score 3):

I remember his dark cartoons from National Lampoon 50 years ago. And when I say dark, I mean, probably not something that would not be censored in most places. One was entitled Hide and Seek -- I wonder if anyone remembers the one I am referring to? I don't want to give it away but if u did see it in 1972 or so, I bet u remember it too.